# Eclipse Helios Deployment Issue

Tags: eclipse, helios

I am using Helios Version of Eclipse. I am having an issue using that. I have created a Dynamic Web project there. I have some .jar files under WebRoot/WEB-INF/lib folder. With all other .jar files I have a .jar file called iText-2.1.5.jar. I am using GlassFish server as a Application Server. Now issue is, when I am trying to add this project to the server only previously mentioned .jar file adding seperately into the server . When I am trying to publish any change into the server it is showing an error message like 'Publish failed using Ant publisher Could not delete [.JAR] file....' . To avoid this problem everytime I have to stop the server and manually delete the .jar file from the specific location and then restart the server. This is very time consuming process. Can you guys please solve this problem?

Thanks is advance.

Somnath Guha